# Regular expression unicode replace not working

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have the following example in python, and it's not working:

```
>>> replace = re.compile(ur'најавени', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

>>> docText = replace.sub("најавени1",docText)

>>> print docText

трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал

>>> docText = replace.sub(u"најавени1",docText)

>>> print docText

трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал

>>> docText = replace.sub(u"најавени1",docText,re.IGNORECASE)

>>> print docText

трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал
```

Any hints? I just want to make a replace of a string in text, it's working in english but not in my native language.

Second attempt:

```
>>> docText = "трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал"
>>> replace = re.compile(ur'Најавени', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> docText = replace.sub(u"најавени1",docText,re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print docText
трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал
```

Comment: Are your files that you're trying to match encoded as utf-8?

Comment: try making docText unicode...

Comment: Also you're attempting to match `Најавени` using `најавени` and the `re.I` flag.  The `re.I` flag only works on ASCII range text, it doesn't properly match unicode to my knowledge.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue2834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify unicode aware strings and regular expressions like so:

```
>>> import re
>>> replace = re.compile(ur'најавени', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
>>> docText = u"трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал"
>>> print docText
трендафилов во мвр се Најавени нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал
>>> docText = replace.sub(u"најавени1",docText)
>>> print docText
трендафилов во мвр се најавени1 нови смени поврзани со безбедноста и борбата против организираниот криминал
```